# How to insert values into single linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures

I'm trying to learn some basics about single linked lists, so I went with idea of creating some code. Sadly, I have given constructor to follow.

Untill now I've created all methods I've wanted. Unfortunately, seems like my insert doesn't work, so I can't even check if other methods works. Ofc role of insert method is to add number into sorted list L. This number should be put before first number, if it's bigger or put at the end of the list, if there is no such number.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

struct lnode
{
    int key;
    lnode* next;
    lnode(int k, lnode* n=nullptr):key(k),next(n){}
};

void insert( lnode* &L, int x)
{
    while(L)
    {
        if(x >= L->key)
        {
            L = L->next;
        }
        else
        {
            lnode* temp = L;
            L = new lnode(x, nullptr);
            L->next = temp;
            break;
        }
    }


}

int main()
{
    lnode* t = nullptr;

    insert(t,3);
    insert(t,4);
    insert(t,1);
    insert(t,7);
    insert(t,-4);
    insert(t,9);
    insert(t,2);

        while(L) {
        std::cout << L->key << " ";
    }
}
```

What do I expect? My expectations is to see elements of my list. At this moment there is nothing. No error, no result.

Comment: Are you sure the code compiles at all?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin it does not

Comment: Does this code even compile successfully? Where is L declared in the main function for using it in while(L)?

Comment: If your code doesn't compile there should be an error message. Something has to happen when you attempt to compile or run your program, whether it hangs, crashes, or exits immediately without any output. If absolutely nothing happens, you need to fix your IDE.

Comment: It does. Which is weird. At least using code::blocks. 
Oh yea, swapped L with t and it compiles, but there is output i was talking about. Nothing.

Comment: So when you run it does it exit immediately? Or does it hang?

Comment: Instant: Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time: 0.388 s Press key to continue.

Comment: Most of the time, a linked list is a *terrible* data structure to use. In most cases, a `std::vector` is what you want. Unless you need objects to never be moved in memory.  The algorithmic complexity arguments that say list insertions/removals are fast compared to vectors are completely negated by the way modern hardware works and the costs of chasing pointers all over memory are (usually) far greater than the cost involved in copying vector elements. And for simple traversals, vector always wins.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Singly linked lists are used all the time in real life , but not as collections.  They arise naturally in objects that are linked together, like inheritance chains, etc.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I did not say they do not occur. Nor did I say they don't have a use case. I just said that they are *usually* not what you want *if* you can use something else. They are a bad default choice.

Comment: @AndrewMean [It doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d5e8df29d3c14d3). I hardly believe even in CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to writing simple singly-linked list modifying code is to use a pointer to the pointer current node to indicate your position:

```
void insert( lnode* &L, int x)
{
    lnode **pos = &L;
    while (*pos && (*pos)->key <= x) {
        pos = &((*pos)->next);
    }
    *pos = new lnode(x,*pos);
}
```

Since you are, as you say, a beginner, maybe you should start with the beginner version:

```
void insert( lnode* &L, int x)
{
    if (!L || L->key > x) {
        //insert at head
        L = new lnode(x, L);
        return;
    }
    lnode *previous=L;
    lnode *current=L->next;
    while(current && current->key <= x) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    //insert between previous and current
    previous->next = new lnode(x, current);
}
```

Comparing to the previous one shows the benefit of using `lnode **` to track the insert position as you search:

- no special case for inserting at the head
- no separate variables for previous and next

Comment: It could work, but like I've said, I want to learn some "basics" (if you could call linked list basic), so pointer to pointer is something I cant survive. Dont know whats going on.
Or you know what? I'm gonna learn how it works. If not now, then never. thanks :D

Comment: I don't see the need for a pointer to a pointer here. What prevents you from taking `L` by value and then assigning to it? `while (L && L->key <= x) { L = L->next; }`. Keep track of the previous node if you need to. Or even just `while (L->nest && L->nest->key <= x) { L = L->next }`. When the loop breaks you just insert after `L`. This is much easier than a double pointer.

Comment: Error after error. I just can't imagine how to write it like you said.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang since `L` is a *reference*, `L = L->next` actually deletes the node at the head of the list.

Comment: @AndrewMean I added an easier version for you

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. Fixed the compilation error and also the traversing logic while printing on top of Matt's code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

struct lnode
{
    int key;
    lnode* next;
    lnode(int k, lnode* n = nullptr) :key(k), next(n) {}
};

void insert(lnode* &L, int x)
{
    lnode **pos = &L;
    while (*pos && (*pos)->key <= x) {
        pos = &((*pos)->next);
    }
    *pos = new lnode(x, *pos);
}

int main()
{
    lnode * t = nullptr;

    insert(t, 3);
    insert(t, 4);
    insert(t, 1);
    insert(t, 7);
    insert(t, -4);
    insert(t, 9);
    insert(t, 2);

    while (t) {
        std::cout << t->key << " ";
        t = t->next;
    }
}
```